# x and y variables are from different data frame (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm learning ggplot2 so please excuse my novice understanding.

Is there a way to do a simple scatter plot when x and y are from two different data frames? For example:

```
p <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x.in.df1))
p + geom_point(data=df2, aes(y=y.in.df2))
```

Since `x.in.df1` does not exist in df2, when geom_point tries to look for `x` in `df2`, it fails.

EDIT: The reason why I hesitate to `cbind` is because I have many data frames with the same variables. For example, df2000 contains variables GDP, GDP growth for all countries in year 2000. df2001 is the same for year 2001.

Comment: why don't you cbind the two datasets?

Comment: Because these multiple datasets have the same variables. Eg GDP, GDP growth, etc. for year 2000, 2001, etc.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what your data look like (years? GDP? etc.) Please provide us with some dummy data that mimic your real dataset(s).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's the standard cross-country dataset. For example: df2000 contains variables GDP, GDP growth, etc. for all countries in year 2000. df2001 is the same for year 2001. Can I plot with x coming from df2000 and y coming from df2001?

Comment: what's preventing you from using x from df2001?

Comment: x (let's say GDP) from df2000 is GDP in year 2000. x from df2001 is GDP in year 2001. They are different variables with a same name.

Comment: I would use cbind() regardless, and find a good naming scheme for the clashes in column names.

Comment: Why don't you use `ggplot(data=data.frame(x=df1$x,y=df2$y), aes(x=x,y=y))`?

Comment: Yes, thanks Roland! If you wish, please submit that as an answer so that I can highlight it.

Answer (score 3):

Credit goes to @Roland; I'm just posting his comment as an answer here for future readers like myself who encounter the same/similar problems.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = df1$x, y = df2$y), aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Thanks for the elegant solution @Roland.